# PC to router to router, what's the IP of the first router?

Tags: networking, ip, router

**Tl;dr**: PC connect do router that is connected to the service provider's router. I can access the service provider router (192.168.1.1) but I can't connect to my own router.

I live in a rented with a lousy wi-fi signal (router is for the whole floor). Asked for a rj45 inside my home, bought a [ASUS RT-N10E](https://www.asus.com/Networking/RTN10E/).

They are all connect by wire. In the asus manual the ip addres is the same as the one of the service providers (192.168.1.1) and if I enter this ip in chrome I get to the page from the service provider router, I can't access my own router. (and the other ip i see there 192.168.1.0 goes nowhere)

I already did a factory reset on the router... No change.

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0


ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:cf:30:6c:e2:c1  
          inet addr:192.168.1.11  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::22cf:30ff:fe6c:e2c1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:122918 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:68378 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:172637632 (172.6 MB)  TX bytes:5266306 (5.2 MB)
          Interrupt:50 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:4204 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4204 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:443876 (443.8 KB)  TX bytes:443876 (443.8 KB)


 ip route show default
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  proto static 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.11  metric 1
```

Comment: Which port of the new router are you chaining to? The simplest configuration would be to connect via one of the LAN ports and configure the additional router as a dumb WAP / switch: see [How To Convert a Wireless Router into an Access Point](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/basics/wireless-basics/30338-how-to-convert-a-wireless-router-into-an-access-point) for example.

Comment: my problem is not being able to get to the config page from my own router ( noob me)

Comment: you would be able to access the config page by disconnecting your router from the service providers one and connecting your computer directly to your router. you can try accessing the config page by going to the routers ip address in your browser

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). You asked this on [su]: [PC to router to router, what's the IP of the first router?](http://superuser.com/q/987998)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said: `In the asus manual the ip addres is the same as the one of the service providers (192.168.1.1)` I suggest you disconnect the Asus router temporarily, connect to it with ethernet and change the Asus IP address to 192.168.0.1. Reconnect and you are all set.

Comment: I used zenmap to see all in the network and suddenly there was an 192.168.1.3  :) done. trhnx anyway